# How to print full path for libs using otool?

Tags: macos, otool

`otool` show me paths with `@rpath`, how can I expand `@rpath` to get full path?

```
otool -L my_lib.so | grep opencv

@rpath/libopencv_objdetect.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
@rpath/libopencv_video.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
@rpath/libopencv_calib3d.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
@rpath/libopencv_features2d.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
@rpath/libopencv_highgui.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
@rpath/libopencv_videoio.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
@rpath/libopencv_imgcodecs.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
@rpath/libopencv_imgproc.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
@rpath/libopencv_flann.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)
@rpath/libopencv_core.3.4.dylib (compatibility version 3.4.0, current version 3.4.1)

otool -l my_lib.so | grep opencv

     name @rpath/libopencv_objdetect.3.4.dylib (offset 24)
     name @rpath/libopencv_video.3.4.dylib (offset 24)
     name @rpath/libopencv_calib3d.3.4.dylib (offset 24)
     name @rpath/libopencv_features2d.3.4.dylib (offset 24)
     name @rpath/libopencv_highgui.3.4.dylib (offset 24)
     name @rpath/libopencv_videoio.3.4.dylib (offset 24)
     name @rpath/libopencv_imgcodecs.3.4.dylib (offset 24)
     name @rpath/libopencv_imgproc.3.4.dylib (offset 24)
     name @rpath/libopencv_flann.3.4.dylib (offset 24)
     name @rpath/libopencv_core.3.4.dylib (offset 24)
```

> -l     Display the load commands.
>
> -L     Display the names and version numbers of  the  shared
> libraries that  the  object file uses, as well as the shared library
> ID if the file is a shared library.

Comment: You will find the rpath in the results of `otool -l`

Comment: @RichardBarber actually output is about the same.

Comment: Use the RPATH value from `otool -l` to substitute `@rpath` in the installed path.

Comment: Don't pipe to `grep` as that obliterates the RPATH value.